# Calling method from another method?

Tags: java, methods

I'm semi-new to programming and I am having trouble calling a method inside another method. I'm not completely done writing my code but was checking to make sure it is working as intended as I go. So there are other errors in the code but I'm assuming it shouldn't matter for the part I have below.

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Press n to add a new account\n Press d to add a deposit\n "
            + "Press w to withdraw from an account\n Or press x to exit");        
    String choice = input.next();        
    if(choice.equals("n")){
            Bank n = new Bank();
            n.newAccount();
    }

public void newAccount() {
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the account number");
```

So my problem is that it prompts me to enter n/d/w/x as it should in the first part, but then nothing else happens when I enter "n". Where as I thought after entering n it would prompt me for the account number.

FYI: the name of the class is Bank. Also the code is a little lengthy so I only pasted a portion of it (there are more if statements for entering d/w/x and there are other methods to the program as well.

Comment: As the scope of your `Bank` object is limited to your `if` statement, it may not be doing what you are wanting.  However what you are wanting is impossible to guess.

Comment: Try putting a debug statement in your `if` statement to ensure that it is being called.

Comment: but why u making new object for the calling that method?

Comment: Not really sure, is there another way to call the method without doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the "choice" variable to the return from the input dialog, as it returns the user's input as a string, like so:

```
String choice = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Press n to add a new account\n Press d to add a deposit\n "
            + "Press w to withdraw from an account\n Or press x to exit");
```

Check out this tutorial for more info: [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to throw this in a debugger and it will be very clear.

One thing to check is to make sure is the input you are getting is really 'n'.

Perhaps put a print statement right after variable choice is initialized.

```
System.out.println(String.format("Choice '%s'", choice));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try out by yourself by printing `choice` value or if you are using any IDE then starting server in debug mode and then inspecting whatever you want to inspect by applying debug points in code.